# Audio sounds oddly distorted

Tags: noise, distortion

https://clips.twitch.tv/TangentialObliqueLobsterSaltBae
https://clips.twitch.tv/CharmingBashfulAlfalfaRickroll
https://clips.twitch.tv/NaiveKindGorillaGivePLZ

(Disclaimer: These were not recorded on or uploaded from my computer.)

In the 1st video linked above, the water sloshing sounds heavily distorted and the same type of "noise" heard throughout that segment of the clip can be heard periodically throughout this person's videos, including the other ones I linked.

<s>I've been trying to help this person hear the problem with his audio, but he's not hearing it and</s> I'm not entirely sure what the cause of it could be or how one could even describe it.

EDIT: He switched to different broadcasting software and finally hears how bad it sounds now. Now we just need to know the cause.

Comment: I can't hear anything too odd. Would it be possible to isolate the sound channel, capture it in a sound file and open it with something like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/)? You can then mark the areas that sound problematic so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: You should ask how they record the audio. Is it just leakage from the headphone to the microphone(s)?

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo He records the audio (game and microphone) through a non-virtual mixer, which is hooked up to the computer he streams to. There is no leakage to the microphone as far he's told me, but I'll ask him again when he's on later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We determined that it was his broadcasting software that was causing the issue. He switched to a new broadcasting software and the audio sounds clean again. Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

It's mono, not stereo like one would expect, and it sounds like exacerbated compression artifacts to me, like in the difference signal between the stereo channels of a lossy compressed audio, but I'm not sure if that explains everything.

Given that he uses an external mixer for recording, there may be a simple explanation: He has connected a stereo cable to a balanced input of the mixer. The balanced input will typically take the left channel as "hot" and right channel as "cold", and will effectively see the mono difference signal: hot minus cold. He should use a stereo to 2x mono splitter cable, or use a stereo input in the mixer if available.

Comment: This is definitely helpful in explaining how it sounds. I couldn't quite explain it as anything more than a "wishy sound", but your observation definitely sounds more accurate.

Comment: @LordNazo I edited my answer with the new information about the mixer.